# Inner static Class object is being returned as anonymous

Tags: typescript, builder, react-typescript

I have written builder design pattern implementation using inner static class in typeScript.

```
export class BioData {
        private name: string | undefined;
        private age: number | undefined;
        private section: string | undefined;
    
        static Builder = class {
            protected name: string | undefined;
            protected age: number | undefined;
            protected section: string | undefined;
    
            setName(name: string): this {
                this.name = name;
                return this;
            }
    
            setAge(age: number): this {
                this.age = age;
                return this;
            }

            setSection(section: string): this {
                this.section = section;
                return this;
            }
    
            populate(instance: BioData): void {
                instance.setName(this.name);
                instance.setAge(this.age);
                instance.setSection(this.section);
            }
    
            build(): BioData {
                const instance = new BioData();
                this.populate(instance);
                return instance;
            }
        };
    
        constructor(public builder?: typeof BioData.Builder) {}
    
        setName(name: string | undefined) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        setAge(age: number | undefined) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        setSection(section: string | undefined) {
            this.section = section;
       }
    }
```

when i'm trying to create the object in below way.

```
const bioDataBuilder = new BioData.Builder();
const bioData: BioData = bioDataBuilder.setName("Shivanshu").setAge(15).secSection("A").build();
```

here the type returned by `bioDataBuilder.setName("Shivanshu")` is anonymous type(No name). but it should be `BioData.Builder`. So when i'm trying to call `setAge(15)` method on object returned by `setName("Shivanshu")`, this is calling `setMethod of BioData class`. which is actually wrong.

Can some one please help why the typeReturned by `setName("Shivanshu")` is `anonymous type`, although i'm returning `this` from setName method defined in Inner Static class. How can i make it to returning BioData.Builder.

Thanks.

Comment: "this is throwing compile time error" <-- exactly what error and on which line?  There also seem to be other errors unrelated to what you're asking.  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wEGdym) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  There should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: I did not find a solution to your weird errors. However, I did create a dynamic builder creator using `Proxy` which should make your code simpler if you are willing to use it. Here it is  tinyurl.com/4jfafmhc (I needed to shorten)

Comment: @jcalz, yeah sorry for the churn, i've modified the question. code-part should be error-free now. Please take a look. Apart from that online platform is giving some errors for builder inner static class , which i'm not getting in my local IDE.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still can't reproduce your issue: [see this](https://tsplay.dev/NrGpam).  The type returned by `setName("Shivanshu")` is not `BioData` but `(Anonymous class)` (since, after all, it has no name as it was declared via an anonymous class *expression* instead of a class declaration *statement*).  I strongly suggest you try to get your problem to occur in some web IDE that everyone can look at.  Otherwise your question is about something specific to your local environment, which is much harder for me to answer, since I have no access to that environment.

Comment: @jcalz, yeah, why this is anonymous class. I think that's the root cause. How can i make it to return BioData.Builder.

Comment: I do wonder why your question does not mention "anonymous class" and instead talks about `BioData` which is not reproducible; can you [edit] the question to describe the actual issue?  If you want `BioData.Builder` to be a *type* name then you need to treat `BioData` like a `namespace` or `module`.  Class members do not export type names.  You can export `Builder` directly from a `BioData` module like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMVAQW); does that meet your needs? If so I can maybe write up an answer; if not, can you explain what's missing?

Comment: Note that `secSection` is a typo and should probably be fixed/removed from the question as well.

Comment: Let me try it in Local RDE, will confirm soon.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for the support, this seems to be getting compiled. will check it thoroughly and get back to you later.  As of now you can write up the answer.

Comment: I'll write up an answer after the question has been edited to make a reference to your actual issue (i.e., that the exposed builder instance type has no name) as opposed to a non-issue (i.e., that the builder instance type is `BioData`, which it isn't).

Comment: done now! Thanks for the help. 